# Why this route goes to the show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

This request goes to SHOW action in Webservices controller..

```
 Reuest : webservices/getsomething&ids=1
```

This

```
 Reuest : webservices/getsomething
```

goes where I wanted at getsomething action ...
This is my route.rb :

```
  resources :webservices do
    collection do
      get 'getsomething'
    end
  end
```

rake routes :

```
  getsomething_webservices GET    /webservices/getsomething(.:format)              webservices#getsomething
```

and still rails go in show action ???

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
get "getsomething/:id"
```

Comment: And change your request to be "id=1" not "ids=1"

Answer (score 1):

You have error in your url. It should be `webservices/getsomething?ids=1`. Change & to ?

Comment: This is right .. I am working on backend for some application and take for granted that calls is ok ... in angular controller script I change & with ? and everything is working .. Thanks !